# Is there a stacked pie chart that I can use with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#.  All of the pie chart controls that I see will only allow each category to be assigned one value.

For example, I could make a list of email campaigns and associate each campaign with a number of messages sent.

But what I want to do is show a pie chart which displays multiple values per campaign.  For example, each campaign would show the number of messages sent, number failed, and number pending.

Is there any solution for this kind of pie chart in ASP.NET?

Comment: What pie chart are you using? The one that is part of the ms chart library?

Comment: How would you want that to be displayed visually?

Comment: I would show for a campaign: the amount of messages that failed, pending, sent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2D stacked pie chart that allows you to visualize multiple attributes in separate "doughnuts" stacked inside a single chart. Something like this:

[image]

If you're using Microsoft Chart Controls, then here is a [post that describes how to do that](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/MSWinWebChart/thread/29f1b26f-9a2a-416e-acb9-8cf0490a36e0/). Essentially, you'll just create three independent doughnut charts and place them over each other. If you're using some other library, then you'll need to clarify that in your question.

Comment: @Yulimar: It should be easy to translate from VB to C#. If you find something you don't understand, feel free to ask here (or use google :-)).